# Why is the probability of "$\le$" the same as "$\lt$"?

Tags: probability, integration

The current in a certain circuit as measured by an ammeter is a continuous random variable X with the following density function:

$f(x)= 0.075x+0.2$ for $3\le{x}\le5$
$f(x) = 0$        otherwise.

Calculate $P(X\le4)$ and compare to $P(X\lt4)$.

In my solution, I calculate $P(X\le4)$ and $P(X\lt4)$ by integral and I see that $P(X\le4)=P(X\lt4)$. My questions are:

1. Are they always equal to each other in every other case?
2. Why  can they equal to each other while $P(X=4)\neq0$?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: $P(X=4)$ is equal to zero. You seem to be confusing the probability with likelihood.

Comment: for a continuous random variable $X$, $\mathbb{P}(X = c) = 0$ for some constant $c$. Or in measure theory terms, the sets defined by $X \le c$ and $X< c$ have the same exact measure.

Comment: $P(X = 4)$ is $0$. For a continuous random variable the probability of any single value is always zero. So that why it doesn't make a difference if you use $\lt$ or $\le$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a continuous distribution, the probability of it hitting any single value is always 0.  So $P(X=4)=0$,  When you go to calculate it, you will see you are integrating from 4 to 4,  which is obviously 0.   We can only calculate probabilities of ranges of values.

It is only in discrete distributions that you can get a nonzero probability of a single, discrete value.  So yes, for all values in continuous probability,  $P(X<K)=P(X\leq K)$  by additivity of the single 0 value $P(X=K)=0$

Answer (score -1):

To complement the other answer I want to say that probability is, in some sense, a branch of measure theory. That is, probability is a way to assigns to some subsets "a kind of area", or "length", loosely speaking.

And in measure theory you realize you can have sets which although not being empty they have "length" $0$ (for example $A=\{4\}$ in your case). And this is the reason why you can find non impossible events whose probability is $0$.

Comment: Could the "downvoter" explain me the reasons? This way I can learn my mistake